# increasing and decreasing a float value does not work the way i want?

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android app that involves an activity with an xml layout file that has a `textview` and 2 buttons. When you press the plus button the `textview` increments by 0.1 and when you press the minus button the `textview` decrements by 0.1. so in my java code I declare the buttons and the `textview`. I have set up a variable called test as a float which is equal to 0.0.

```
 float test=0.0f;
```

Then in my on click statement I have used a switch case statement for the plus and minus button

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){


        case R.id.increase:

            test = test+0.1f;
            temperatureTextview.setText((test)+"");
            break;
        case R.id.decrease:
            test = test-0.1f;

            temperatureTextview.setText((test)+"");
            break;
    }
```

the app works fine and loads fine the only problem is when I increment or decrement to certain values instead of it showing for example 0.3 or 1.6  in the `textview` the way I want it, it shows 0.30000000009 or 1.600000009. why is it doing this on certain numbers and is there I can get it to the display the numbers exactly how I want it  i.e 1.9, 34.6, 200.5 not 1.600000003? so in other words to one decimal place (if my math serves me right)?

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point numbers! http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use String.format:

```
temperatureTextView.setText(String.format("%5.1f", test));
```

The problem is that floating point arithmetic isn't entirely accurate unless you are using only powers of two. The specifier %5.1f tells it to give you a floating point number with 5 characters (including the decimal) rounded to 1 decimal place.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more about the specifier syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal roundfinalPrice = new BigDecimal(test).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

You can round up the float value as you want...